# How to ensure that byte[ ] is saved as a jpg image through an InputStream in java?

Tags: java, arrays, byte, jpeg, inputstream

I am trying to save an image into an FTPServer using Apache Commons `FTPClient.storeFile(...)` method, which requires an `InputStream`. The image comes as a `Byte[]` at the beginning.

Here some code:

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
boolean  done = ftpClient.storeFile(remotePath, is);
```

However, when I download the uploaded image, it looks very strange and even though the dimensions are respected, the image does not look like it should.
The Image after uploading Looks like this:
[Image after uploading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOClo.jpg)
In reality I do not have access to the original Image but I know it is an Image of the open sea with blue water on it.
Thank you!

Comment: Please include the images, they might help finding the answer

Comment: Can you try writing the image to a local file and check if it looks correct?

Comment: I am showing the Image after uploading as a modification to the post

Comment: If I save it as a local file using a BufferedImage it looks correct. Should this mean that I need to save it first or is there any workaround to be able to stream the byte array into the FTPServer without having to save it locally?

Comment: If the bytes are correct when saved to a file, but seem corrupted when sent via FTP, my first guess would be that the FTP connection is operating in text mode instead of in binary mode.

Comment: Are the bytes really a JPEG already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as [VGR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831987/vgr)! accurately pointed out, the Apache Commons ftpClient has two working modes, ASCII and binary mode. By default the ASCII mode is used and one must enforce the treatment of data as binary data explicitly via

```
    try {            
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```